# Is the cap product $H_p(X,Z)\times H^p(X,Z)\to H_0(X,Z)=Z$ a perfect duality?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Assume that $X$ is a connected topological space (or more specifically a non-necessarily smooth algebraic variety over the complex numbers). **Is the cap product** $$H_p(X,Z)\times H^p(X,Z)\to H_0(X,Z)=Z$$ **a perfect duality**?
In other words, if I fix a basis $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m\in H_p(X,Z),$ can I find $\beta\in H^p(X,Z)$ such that $\alpha_i\cdot \beta =\delta_{i,1}$ ? (I.e. it is equal to one if $i=1$ and zero otherwise?)
I assume this is obvious if $Z$ is replaced by a field.

Thanks!

PS. I would assume that this is very standard, but I couldn't find a reference.

Comment: The universal coefficient theorem quantifies how the induced map $H^p\to \mathrm{Hom}(H_p, Z) $ fails to be an isomorphism through the Ext functor.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example in mind for a complex projective variety when p=2?

Comment: For manifolds, you have Poincare duality.  For singular spaces, I assume there are lots of caveats, failures, and fixes.

Comment: I am asking for a reference with a counterexample. Thanks!

Comment: If $X=\mathbb{R}P^2$, then $H_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$, so $H_1(X)$ doesn't have a basis at all. Also, $H^1(X) = 0$, and there is no nonzero map $H_1(X) \times H^1(X) \to H_0(X)$. Maybe restricting to complex algebraic varieties helps to avoid such situations, but I don't know.